# Matlab Bpm Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, matlab, signal-processing, audio-processing

Does anyone knows where can a find a matlab algorithm to get music tempo (in beats per minute, or some other measure)?
I tried the one from this site: http://www.clear.rice.edu/elec301/Projects01/beat_sync/beatalgo.html
But is not giving me good responses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finding the tempo of a musical signal can be a very difficult task. For a simple signal where a single note is played with a fix tempo, maybe that the method proposed by kol would work but, as mentionned by Oli Charlesworth, I do not think that it would be robust enough to give you a good estimate of the tempo for more complex musical signal.

This has a lot to do with [musical acoustics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Musical_acoustics) (especially the fact that the frequency content of notes played by musical instruments is much more complex than a collection of sine waves) and [psychoacoustics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psychoacoustics) (especially the fact that determining the onset time of a note is influenced by its harmonic content)

A good (though maybe hard to read depending on your background) reference is: ftp://wgs.esat.kuleuven.ac.be/sista/bli/scheirer_jasa.pdf

You should also read the answers and comments to this question on DSP: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/386/autocorrelation-in-audio-analysis.

Answer (score 1):

If you need a single number for a whole music track, then you can do an FFT, and find the largest peak in the relevant frequency band. The frequency of the peak will give you the tempo.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth I believe you, but why?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth I mean Filipe needs an overall "music tempo", which I guess gives the major low-frequency component of the power spectrum. It's very easy to downvote an answer without any explanation.

Comment: My intuition tells me that the frequency-domain information out of an FFT will be so smeared that identifying a meaningful peak would be very unlikely.  There will be all sorts of intermod products all overlapping.  I could be wrong, but I'll believe it when I see it...  (I'll remove my downvote, because I can't prove it's not going to work, though.)

Comment: @OliCharlesworth You can smooth the spectrum, e.g. by calculating it for shorter sections of the signal, and then averaging these (this is a built-in possibility in Matlab).

Comment: +1. While it is unlikely to work, a smoothed FFT is a quite cheap thing to compute in Matlab and definitely worth a try. And, if anything, serves to illustrate that your first attempt at doing anything (well, anything not girlfriend-related) should be a Fourier transform.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried [this package](http://labrosa.ee.columbia.edu/projects/coversongs/) from Columbia, but perhaps it would meet your needs. In particular it contains a function `tempo.m` that calculates the BPM of an audio waveform. It appears to be available under a GPL license.

Hope it works for you!