# How to calculate bandwidth and tempo of an audio signal using Matlab

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

I m doing a project on Music Genre Classification using neural network.I need to extract different features.What is meaning of Bandwidth and tempo and how to find them using Matlab.

Answer (score 1):

A web search for "What is meaning of Bandwidth and tempo and how to find them using Matlab" turned up [this](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/24583-mirtoolbox) and [this](http://www.ee.columbia.edu/~dpwe/e4896/practicals.html).

I recommend you do some reading!

Answer (score 1):

Try Hard is right, you should do some more reading to first figure out what bandwidth and tempo are. The bandwidth of a signal is the width, in Hz, of its spectral range. The The fft command in Matlab will be useful here, you can search Mathworks for a tutorial on how to use it.

As for tempo, here's another Stackoverflow question that has some resources and addresses your question:

[Matlab Bpm Algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8115509/matlab-bpm-algorithm)

Answer (score 0):

A good start is read the paper "Musical Genre Classification of Audio Signals" by George Tzanetakis !

He describe how extract all features, you can found in marsyas a lot of algorithms to extract it http://marsyas.info/

I wrote in matlab the tempo extraction step https://github.com/ederwander/Beat-Track